# В Андроид приложении LibGdx, переполняется Native Heap

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Проблема в том что Native Heap в Андроид приложении все время переполняется.
Проверяется Native Heap  в коде следующим образом:
`Gdx.app.getNativeHeap()`
**Не путать с  Java Heap**
Код в гит:
https://github.com/Zaigard100/DarGon3

Comment: если вы думаете, что кто-то полезет в ваш репозиторий, скачает его и начнет разбираться с парой десятком классов, то вы глубоко заблуждаетесь. Выделите проблемный участок кода вставьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Лучше всего рассматривать класс PlayScreen это класс с основной логикой игры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кароче проблема состояла в том что я каждый кадр для отрисовки использовал вот такой код:

`batch.draw(new Texture (Gdx.file.internal("res/run.png"));`

И эта часть кода все время загружала по новой файл run.png и Native Heap все время увеличивался.

Так вот решение собственно:
Текстуру нужно в водить в переменную:

`public void show(){ .... ; run = new Texture (Gdx.file.internal("res/run.png"));...}`

И в методе отрисовки:

`public void render(){...; batch.draw(run);..}`

И не забываем:

`run.dispose()`

Вот и результаты:

До:
[image: До]
После:
[image: После]

Answer (score 1):

Если переполняется Native Heap, то очевидно не происходит освобождение нативных ресурсов, т.е. не вызывается метод `dispose()` у объектов. Например, в `GameScreen` я нашел такие ошибки:

1. Создание `SpriteBatch` и `FrameBuffer` желательно вынести в конструктор
2. В методе `resize(int width, int height)` надо сначала вызвать fbo.dispose() и fbo2.dispose(), а потом уже заново создавать
3. При смене экрана текущий экран надо также dispose'ить

Я так подозреваю, что подобных ошибок в проекте очень много

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет.

Comment: @Zaigard если помогло, пометьте ответ галочкой пожалуйста)) человек старался

Comment: Сори. Не помогло.